# it is keep on printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator

when i run this code it keeps on giving me the answer
here is my code

```
num1 = float(raw_input("enter a number: "))  # type: float
operation = str(raw_input("enter a operation: "))
num2 = float(raw_input("enter a number: "))  # type: float

  while True:
        if operation == "+":
           print num1 + num2
        elif operation == "-":
           print num1 - num2
        elif operation == "*":
           print num1 * num2
        elif operation == "/":
           print (num1 / num2)
        else:
           print("Error Error")
```

Comment: That’s because you put the lines that do printing in a loop `while True:` - you don’t need the while statement.

Comment: Or you want to put the whole thing in while loop so that it can ask user many times.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want is to put the input taking code into the while loop:

```py
while True:
    num1 = float(raw_input("enter a number: "))  # type: float
    operation = str(raw_input("enter a operation: "))
    num2 = float(raw_input("enter a number: "))  # type: float
    
    if operation == "+":
        print (num1 + num2)
    elif operation == "-":
        print (num1 - num2)
    elif operation == "*":
        print (num1 * num2)
    elif operation == "/":
        print (num1 / num2)
    else:
        print("Error Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`while True:` means Infinite Loop.
```

You can take input inside while loop or you can change the condition of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `while True:` and it will only print out the answer once. `while` loops continue running as long as the argument is true and `True` is always true :P

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is for the application to keep calculating input from the user.

Try this

```py
def calculate():
    num1 = float(raw_input("enter a number: "))  # type: float
    operation = str(raw_input("enter a operation: "))
    num2 = float(raw_input("enter a number: "))  # type: float
    
    if operation == "+":
        print (num1 + num2)
    elif operation == "-":
        print (num1 - num2)
    elif operation == "*":
        print (num1 * num2)
    elif operation == "/":
        print (num1 / num2)
    else:
        print("Error Error")

while True:
    calculate()
```

Comment: thank you for helping me solve this